# Is there any way to set start datetime for accesslogs API of Slack?

Tags: slack, slack-api

API in the question: https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs

I want fetch the accesslogs only after a certain date, I don't want access logs since the beginning of time everytime I call this API because I am already storing the accesslogs in my database each time I make this call. The API does not seem to have the parameter that can be given for start date.

Answer (score 1):

You should limit the number of result per page with the 'count' optional argument, compare the time of each result with your last saved date and paginate until you reach your date limit.

Unfortunately, Slack does not provide a way to use a starting date as a limit.

Comment: which date should I compare, date_first or date_last, I don't want to miss any events?

Comment: According to the documention `date_last is the most recent for that combination.`, I woud look at date_last if I were you.

(source: https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs)